# Zero-knowledge sequencing of messages

Tags: cryptography, zkp

I have multiple servers (for redundancy) sending data to clients. The clients need to process these messages in sequence and ignore duplicates.

We use external information to determine a special sequencing string that is deterministic across all our servers, as it would be too slow to keep the servers in sync.

The sequencing strings generated have remnants of top-secret information in them, and we can't reveal them to the clients.

1. Suppose the sequencing string just contains an integer. Is there a way of hashing this data such that the clients can order the messages without learning any additional information about its content?
2. Suppose a more complicated sequence string is used. The string is split into sub-sequences, and each sub-sequence is given a category, something like "a:12477/t:637" and "a:12477/e:456", where the comparison function between sequences is given below. Is it possible to hash the sequencing string in such a way that even a complicated function like this can operate on the data and nothing else?

JavaScript pseudo-code:

```
function compare(seq_a: string, seq_b: string) {
  function decode(seq) {
    seq_a.split("/").map(segment => {
      let [category, sub_seq] = segment.split(":");
      return { category, sub_seq: Number(sub_seq) }
    });
  }

  let a = decode(seq_a);
  let b = decode(seq_b);

  for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(a.length, b.length); i++) {
    let segment_a = a[i] || { category: "empty", sub_seq: 0 };
    let segment_b = b[i] || { category: "empty", sub_seq: 0 };

    if (segment_a.category != segment_b.category) {
      return "UNKNOWN";
    }

    if (segment_a.sub_seq > segment_b.sub_seq) {
      return "A";
    } else if (segment_a.sub_seq < segment_b.sub_seq) {
      return "B";
    } else if (segment_a.sub_seq == segment_b.sub_seq) {
      continue;
    }
  }

  return "UNKNOWN";
}
```

I have very little knowledge in the cryptographic and zero-knowledge area so there's nothing I have yet tried, so the furthest I have gotten is just realizing the idea of what is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think using something like Zero Knowledge for this would be a vast overkill. I'd at least start by thinking of all sorts of other stuff.

Here are some ideas, some of them are probably not feasible, depending on your exact use case:

1. Add some salt to the strings, which hides the secret data. So for example if we say that the original data has integers 3 7 and 15: generate random salt (say it's 5), add it to all of the numbers and then send then onwards. You can change the salt regularly, according to some rules.
2. Generate the ordering information without the secret data. So don't share the secret data, but only share generated ordering info. Your internal database can then map between the order data and secret data, when needed.

In any case, I think it would be quite difficult to accomplish this with ZK stuff. Maybe some sort of homomorphic encryption, but that's again a lot more complicated and still under heavy research.